# How to scale y-axis to magnify low values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This plot was produced with matplotlib. The characteristic shape of the values is a peak at the beginning which rapidly drops. However, even a small difference between values is important. How can I scale the y-axis so that this difference is emphasized?

[image]

Comment: I think scaling the y-axis does not help... I would add a lower panel showing the difference between the two curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use log scale. You can do it with `myplot.set_yscale('log')`. Or just use `matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy(x, y)` to plot.

See some examples on [matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html).